# checking next x rows if value occurs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe including two columns which denote events A and B (0 and 1 for happening / not happening respectively). I want to create a new column, C, which is True if B happend within 72 rows of A happening.

Using iterrows (twice) takes too long because of the dataframe size. Is there another approach?

Comment: Iteration with iterrows is good approach for that kind of problem when you have no pattern and need to access previous rows. It could be possible to make it faster with numpy arrays.

here's some info about performance for iterrows vs numpy https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6

Comment: please provide a [mcve]